# Closedness of finite-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, gn.general-topology

Is the (algebraic) span a finite set of vectors in a Hausdorff topological vector space over a complete field always closed?

I suspect yes, but I can't come up with a proof, and it seems like locally convex might be needed to get this.

Comment: Yes, this is true.  I assigned it as a HW problem in a course last spring and a student solved it.  I asked him to type it up, but apparently I don't have it. :(  Anyway, sure, the proof that works over $\mathbb{R}$ (found e.g. in Rudin's *Functional Analysis*) goes over verbatim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This holds indeed for complete fields: see Theorem 2, Section I.2.3, of Bourbaki's "Espaces Vectoriels Topologiques".

Here is the argument.

Let $K$ be a (not necessarily commutative) field equipped with a complete nontrivial [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Fields) $x\mapsto|x|$, let $n$ be a positive integer, let $\tau$ be a Hausdorff vector space topology on $K^n$, and let $\pi$ be the product topology on $K^n$.

**THEOREM** $\tau=\pi$.

**REMINDER** A topological group $G$ is Hausdorff iff {1} is closed. [Proof: {1} is closed $\Rightarrow$ the diagonal of $G\times G$ is closed (because it's the inverse image of {1} under $(x,y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$) $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is Hausdorff.]

**LEMMA** The Theorem holds for $n=1$.

**The Lemma implies the Theorem.** We argue by induction on $n$. The continuity of the identity from $K^n_\pi$ to $K^n_\tau$ (obvious notation) is clear (and doesn't use the Lemma). To prove the continuity of the identity from $K^n_\tau$ to $K^n_\pi$, it suffices to prove the continuity of an arbitrary nonzero linear form $f$ from $K^n_\tau$ to $K_\pi$. By induction hypothesis, the kernel of $f$ is closed, and the Theorem follows from the Reminder and the Lemma.

**Proof of the Lemma.** We'll use several times the fact that $K^\times$ contains elements of arbitrary large and arbitrary small absolute value. As already observed, we have $\tau\subset\pi$. If $x$ is in $K^\times$, write $B_x$ for the open ball of radius $|x|$ and center 0 in $K$. Let $a$ be in $K^\times$, and let $\tau_0$ be the set of those $U$ such that $0\in U\in\tau$.

It suffices to check that $B_a$ contains some $U$ in $\tau_0$.

We can find a $b$ in $K^\times$ and a $V$ in $\tau_0$ such that $a$ is not in $B_bV$, and then a $c$ in $K$ with $|c|>1$ and a $W$ in $\tau_0$ such that $a$ is not in $B_cW$. Then $U:=c^{-1}W$ does the job.

Comment: Umm, I wouldn't have known how to prove this result, but I don't see how it addresses my question, either.

Comment: You asked if a finite dimensional space F in a Hausdorff topological vector space over a complete field is always 
closed. The result I prove (following Bourbaki) shows that 
F (equipped with the induced topology) is complete, and 
thus closed.

Comment: How do you show that every complete field has an absolute value that induces its topology?

Comment: I'm afraid I misunderstood your question. I took it for 
granted that you considered only fields complete with 
respect to a nontrivial absolute value. Sorry. [I know 
nothing about other kinds of complete fields.]

Comment: Your answer is still more general (and so better) than Robin's. [If you don't know what another kind of complete field would be, see Definition, Completeness, and Example 3 at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space ]

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean Example 3 in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Examples ? I don't see there an 
example of complete topological field whose topology is 
not given by an absolute value. 

Comment: Yeah, I haven't been able to come up with one either.  I just thought it was possible you didn't know how a complete field would be defined without an absolute value.

Comment: Thanks! I can't really say I KNOW the notion of uniform 
space. I just knew such a notion existed, I thought 
(apparently correctly) that it was due to Weil, and I 
knew it played an important role in several Bourbaki's 
books... It's one of the many things I'm planning to 
learn sometime... 

Comment: Quick note: This argument seems to also work for ordered fields as well as valued fields. No idea about other fields.

Comment: I just needed to cite this result in a paper, and literally thought "I know that this result must be somewhere in Bourbaki, but don't want to go hunting; let me Google MO instead, and hope that someone has already done the hunting for me."  Thank you for being that one!

Answer (score 5):

For real/complex vector spaces, this is Theorem 1.21 in Rudin's
*Functional Analysis* (2nd ed.). I believe the proof works for any
complete field, but haven't checked in detail.

Comment: This holds indeed for complete fields: see Theorem 2, Section I.2.3, of Bourbaki's "Espaces Vectoriels Topologiques".


Comment: Very interesting. Clearly Bourbaki was the right place!