# Does the weak approximation theorem hold for general topological fields?

Tags: gn.general-topology, linear-algebra, topological-groups, uniform-spaces, fields

The weak approximation theorem states that given a field $F$ and nontrivial inequivalent absolute values $|\cdot|_1,\ldots,|\cdot|_n,$ and letting $F_i$ denote $F$ with the topology from $|\cdot|_i$, then the diagonal in $F_1 \times \ldots \times F_n$ is dense.

So suppose now we have the same setup, except now the topologies don't necessarily come from absolute values (but do make $F$ a topological field, and are all still distinct and nondiscrete and of course Hausdorff).  Does the result still hold?

Related to [this older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71110/finite-dimensional-vector-spaces-over-a-complete-but-not-necessarily-valued-field) in that one way to come up with a counterexample for both simultaneously would be to find a field with two (nondiscrete, Hausdorff) topologies with one strictly finer than the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel silly -- this is answered early on in Wiesław's "Topological Fields" now that I look.  The answer is no, distinct (non-discrete) topologies on a field need not be independent, they can be comparable, or even incomparable but still dependent.

For a simple example, take two values on the rationals; the topology generated by both together will still make the rationals a topological field, and is not discrete, and is strictly finer than either of the ones you started with.

I think you can recover it if you add some conditions weaker than coming from an absolute value, but, well, now you know where to look for this sort of thing...